# Refresh UI after downloading data from server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to download few data and display all the information in a colection view. I am downloading the data in a for loop. I  want to refresh the UI after downloading the first data from server. But it is refreshing the UI after downloading all the data. This is taking lot of time and obviously the user would not wait for so long.As soon as the data is saved locally I am refreshing UI like this,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:self];
```

The collection view delegates are getting called very late. How should I handle this situation.

Comment: On which thread does the download handling take place?

Answer (score 0):

If your method of refreshing the content, using `NSNotificationCenter`, works, then you should call it on the main thread which you are probably calling in a block.

Just wrap this around your current code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:self];
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not calling the delegate methods immediately. refresh calls this method:- -(void)refresh:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    [[self collect]setDelegate:self];
    [[self collect]setDataSource:self];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
    [[self alerts]reloadData];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    
} It hits this method in no time but delegates call very late... PLease help me out